# Symfony CSV file and ManyToMany attribute

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload, many-to-many

I have a form where I can import a csv file and choose a group to add it to ( its a manytomany association) , I am using this code to import a csv file

```
 public function addEmails(Request $request, ValidatorInterface $validator, SluggerInterface $slugger)
 {
 $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
     $form = $this->createForm(EmailsType::class); 
 $form->handleRequest($request);
    
 if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
     /** @var UploadedFile $uploadedFile */
      
        $file = $form->get('Email')->getData();   
     
     
     if (($handle = fopen($file->getPathname(), "r")) !== false) {
         
         while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== false) {
             // Do the processing: Map line to entity, validate if needed
             $emails = new Emails();
             // Assign fields
             $emails->setEmail($data[0]);

         
             $entityManager->persist($emails);
          
            
         }

         fclose($handle);
         $entityManager->flush();
     }
```

The thing is that the content of the file is supposed to be stored in "Emails" table in data base which it does fine , its id are also supposed to be added to an association table called "emails_groupe" along with the id of the group i chose in the form , which is NOT HAPPENING
this is my form :

```
{{ form_start(emailsform) }} 

 {{ form_row(emailsform.Email, {label_attr: {class: 'custom-file'} }) }}
    {{ form_row(emailsform.idGroupe, {label_attr: {class: 'checkbox-custom'} }) }}

 {{ form_row(emailsform.save) }} 

 {{ form_end(emailsform) }}
```

and my EmailformType

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
           ->add('Email',FileType::class,['required' => true])
       
        ->add('idGroupe', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Groupe::class,
            'choice_label' => 'Titre',
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true,
            'required' => true,
        ])       
    
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class)
```

I don't know what it's missing so help please

Comment: Did you try to debug your code with "dump" functions? to see what's happening. Please add your entities and also the full form type to your question

Answer (score 0):

The job is done in your controller:

```
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        /** @var UploadedFile $uploadedFile */
        // You get your file here
        $file = $form->get('Email')->getData();   
        // You read your file
        if (($handle = fopen($file->getPathname(), "r")) !== false) {
            // For each line in your file, you do some job
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== false) {
                // create a new email
                $emails = new Emails();
                // Assign fields
                $emails->setEmail($data[0]);
                // Save the email
                $entityManager->persist($emails);
                // Missing the second part !!!!!
            }
            fclose($handle);
            $entityManager->flush();
        }
    }
```

If your association table is defined in your ORM as EmailsGroup, then just add the following:

```
$emailGroup = new EmailsGroup();
$emailGroup->setEmail($data[0])
           ->setGroup($form->get('idGroupe')->getData());
$entityManager->persist($emails);
```

If it is a oneToMany association and ou can set the group on the email directly, then add:

```
$mail->setGroup($form->get('idGroupe')->getData());
```